# How to parse a .blend file or a SDNA structure file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, blender

I have been working with Blender's Fluid Designer. Currently, I have to parse the data from its saved .blend file. So far, I have been parsing through a python script that uses the field data point address to show the data but now I'm not able to parse a certain kind of data field using this approach.

This command I'm using to run my script from the command prompt:

```
blender.exe --background myFile.blend --python ./version/scripts/addons/superScript.py
```

(Above command line reference is from another StackOverflow asked question)

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to start with the old [wiki page detailing blenders file format](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Dev:Source/Architecture/File_Format/).

The most recent work is the [Blender Asset Tracer](https://developer.blender.org/source/blender-asset-tracer/) which should do what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for providing the appropriate answer and also for educating me about Blender Asset Tracer. It's really helpful.